# Is there a way to get the URL for the docusign template step 2 page(adding fields page)?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to display the templates edit page in my app using Iframe, particularly the page where we can drag and drop the fields.
I found the api `TemplateViews: createEdit` gives the URL to the template details page. But couldn't find any support for the edit page(step 2) of the template. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by adding a query parameter to the URL
(the URL you get from the API call, not the endpoint of the API itself).

Add `send=0` if you want the first page (recipients and documents).

Add `send=1` if you want the second page (tagger).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped.